# iOS Objective-C webview link button to webpage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

So I have been looking round and can't seem to find an answer to this. In my Objective-C app inside ViewController.m, I am wrapping my web app in a webview like such:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myapp.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

and I have followed a tutorial which allows me to add a toolbar as such:
[image]

going back and forward is fine, but thats not what I want. I want to be able to have button such as "Login" which will take me to https://myapp.com/signin etc. But I have searched so much but can't seem to find out how to do so.

I'm not quite sure but to test this out in m ViewController.m I am trying:

```
- (IBAction)clicks:(id)sender {

NSURL *spotiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myapp.com/clicks"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:spotiURL options:@{}  completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
 if (success) {
    NSLog(@"Opened url");
}
}];

}
```

which doesn't seem to do anything. Please help :(

Comment: The code you have now will open up a browser window outside of your app.

Comment: So then how would I open it inside my phone instead any ideas?

Comment: Prepare a NSURLRequest with http://myapp.com/clicks and load the request with UIWebview

Answer (score 0):

The code you have currently simply opens the URL outside of your app by letting iOS handle the opening of the URL. In order to open the URL in your webview, you'd have to modify your code to something like this:

```
- (IBAction)clicks:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myapp.com/clicks"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use the code for forward,backward and stop inside web view .

**In ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

- (IBAction)backButtonTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)forwardButtonTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)StopButtonClick:(id)sender;
```

**In ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"WebView : %@",_webview);
_webview.delegate = self;
[_webview setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
if (!request) {
    UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Data not received due to network connection.Try again..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertview show];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Data loaded...");
}
[_webview loadRequest:request];
}

- (IBAction)backButtonTapped:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back button pressed." message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertview show];
[_webview stopLoading];
NSLog(@"back button pressed");
[_webview goBack];
}
- (IBAction)forwardButtonTapped:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"forward button pressed." message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertview show];
[_webview stopLoading];
NSLog(@"forward button pressed");
[_webview goForward];
}

- (IBAction)StopButtonClick:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Stop button pressed." message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertview show];
[_webview stopLoading];
NSLog(@"Stop button pressed");
}
```

Hope,this helps to someone.

Comment: thank you loads, I am wondering if it's possible to add camera functionality to my web app. I have a route which allows uploading pictures using a form (POST) but I want to be able to use the native camera feature?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,should work

```
- (IBAction)clicks:(id)sender {
NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initwithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myapp.com/clicks"]];
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```